# Is there a virus active in my Ubuntu?

Tags: bug-reporting, trash, debugging

I m Using Ubuntu 13.04. Whenever I insert any external memory card or pan drive, a new folder Trash is generated there, which uses huge space of it..

The most important thing is that it is not visible in Ubuntu. It can be seen in windows though.

Please tell how to remove this bug.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 questions are off topic as per the FAQ. However, this is not a virus. Trash folder is created on the device when you delete files on it within Nautilus, and they will go into that Trash folder. You will need to empty the trash to actually delete the files.

Comment: @oaskamay You should move this to an answer

Comment: Good idea @chaskes

Answer (score 4):

Not a virus. It's hidden from `nautilus` (default Unity GUI filesystem browser) by default. It's visible when you navigate using Terminal (do `ls -h` to include hidden files when listing).

It's a directory where files are put when you delete it via GUI, so you can restore files when they are deleted this way, but not when you do it via Terminal (i.e. `rm $FILE` or `rm -r $DIRECTORY`; they're essentially gone forever).

Read [How to prevent Ubuntu from creating a .Trash-1000 folder when deleting files from a USB flashdrive?](https://superuser.com/questions/169980/what-is-trash-and-trash-1000) for more information about the `.Trash-1000` folder and how to stop it from being created.

In summary, the link I included mentions:

> Don't use the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button only (Otherwise the .Trash-1000 folder
>   will be created)
>
> Press the key combination <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> together to delete then Ubuntu
>   won't create a `.Trash-1000` folder.
>
> (**Note**: If you delete files and folders this way they are gone forever!)

You can safely remove `.Trash-1000`, preferably via Terminal (run `rm -rf .Trash-1000`).